# findViewById returning null from listview OnClickListener

Tags: android

I have a activity_main.xml that has got a listview in it -

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phoneText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="phone">

        </EditText>
       <ListView
            android:id="@+id/contactList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">

        </ListView>
```

This listview has an 'edit' imageview clicking on which should populate the textviews declared in the activity_main.xml. The code for onclick event of the imageview appears below -

```
      View.OnClickListener editRecordHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

       public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
        phone.setText("ABC");
        }
    };
```

But the findViewById is returning null. Please note that the code for populating the listview and the editRecordHandler is in a class different from MainActivity.java.

P.S. Apparently this is not a duplicate post as I have scanned through all the existing posts and only found one to be relevant but wasn't sure about the solution

(https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dS1QVVD_3jI)

Full Code of DBAdapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


private DBHelper dbHelper = null;

public DBAdapter(DBHelper dbHelper) {
    this.dbHelper = dbHelper;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int index) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int index) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item , parent, false);
    }

    ImageView deleteView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    deleteView.setOnClickListener(deleteRecordHandler);
    deleteView.setTag(contact.id);

    ImageView editView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
    editView.setOnClickListener(editRecordHandler);
    editView.setTag(contact.id);

    return view;
}



    View.OnClickListener editRecordHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        TextView phone = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
        phone.setText("ABC");

    }
};


}
```

The List_view_Item.xml follows

```
<LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_del_unselected" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/editButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete_button"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/modeDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: where have You set the imageView onClickListener? You have to set it inside the adapter. Could You please show Your adapter code?

Comment: Updated with the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete edit:**

- First, you are not changing TextView text, but EditText text, right?? Because id phoneText is for EditText.
- Second to get view outside of listview row do like this:

  ```
  @Override    
  public View getView(int index, View view, ViewGroup parent) {    
      if (view == null) {      
          LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());  
          view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item , parent, false);  
      }

      final OnClickListener editRecordHandler = new OnClickListener() {

          @override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              View v2 = parent.getRootView();
              TextView phone = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);
              phone.setText("ABC");
          }
      }

      ImageView deleteView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
      deleteView.setOnClickListener(deleteRecordHandler);
      deleteView.setTag(contact.id);

      ImageView editView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.editButton);
      editView.setOnClickListener(editRecordHandler);
      editView.setTag(contact.id);

      return view;      
  }
  ```

Comment: but how can it be possible to find phoneText in different class?? what OP said _Please note that the code for populating the listview and the editRecordHandler is in a class different from MainActivity.java_

Comment: The findViewById is not working. It says the method is not recognized. Please note that I am using this from inside an adapter i.e. a class that extends BaseAdapter

Comment: Post the code for adapter please. TextView should come from view that is inflated inside adapter

Comment: thanks...but its the same story :(. I am still getting the NullPointer exception.

Comment: Where do you get it? At final TextView phone = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.phoneText);? If yes, then your view is null. Check your xml layout.list_view_item or post it here for us to check

Comment: It is at phone.setText("ABC"); I have updated the main question with the listview.xml. But please note that the elements I am looking for are in the activity_main.xml

Comment: thanks a ton! It solved the issue. I was struggling with this for so many days... :)

Answer (score 0):

`View.findViewById` returns `this` if the View's id matches, false otherwise. `ViewGroup.findViewById` loops on its child to find among them a match with the id you provide. So, if you have set `onClickListener` on a Button, for instance, and inside `onClick` you try to find an `EditText` (or another component that is not the one you clicked), you will get always   `null`

Comment: Ok...so what's the way out? Isn't there something like getParentView()?